# Where do I put cron commands?

Tags: cron

I see a bunch of tutorials for cron commands like

```
0 */5 * * * /some_sript.sh
```

But what file do I put this line of text in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [tag:crontab info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info)

> #### Basic commands
>
> - `crontab -e` Edit crontab.
> - `crontab -l` Show crontab current information.

Also, you'd better write

```
0 */5 * * * /bin/sh /some_sript.sh
```

instead of

```
0 */5 * * * /some_sript.sh
```

That is, indicate the binary executing the script.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run "crontab" command to edit the cron table. Try to "man crontab".